# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).contentWindow is undefined

Tags: javascript

Here's the html:

```
<div id="vid">
<iframe src="https://yewtu.be/embed/jfKfPfyJRdk" height="0px" width="0px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
function volume() {
document.getElementById("vid").contentWindow.getElementById("player_html5_api").volume = 0.2;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to select the container div, not the iframe itself. Try using `querySelector('#vid > iframe')`.

```js
function volume() {
  const iframe = document.querySelector('#vid > iframe')
  if(iframe) {
    iframe.contentWindow.getElementById("player_html5_api").volume = 0.2;
  }
}

volume()
```

```html
<div id="vid">
  <iframe src="https://yewtu.be/embed/jfKfPfyJRdk" height="0px" width="0px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```